# FFMPEG - zero file size when sound enabled

Tags: php, linux, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm having a few problems converting video files from the command line using FFMPEG. I'm using a CentOS server, but unfortunately I don't have shell access.

When I suppress sound using the following command, everything works perfectly (except of course, there's no sound!)

```
ffmpeg -i $infile -an test.flv
```

However, when I try to enable sound in *any* way at all, the file being outputted has a file size of zero kb.

FFMPEG is compiled with support for libmp3lame and libfaac, and the necessary codecs are installed. Here is the configuration of FFMPEG on the server:

> FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
>   configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg --enable-libvorbis --enable-libogg --enable-libtheora --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-xvid --enable-x264 --enable-liba52 --enable-liba52bin --enable-pp --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --disable-strip

Here is a very small sample of some of the commands I've tried that result in a 0Kb file size:

```
ffmpeg -i $infile test.flv
ffmpeg -i $infile -vcodec copy -acodec ac3 test.flv
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -i $infile -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 test.flv
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -i $infile -vcodec copy -acodec copy $outfile
ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -i $infile -vcodec copy -acodec aac $outfile
```

If anyone could provide any hints on what's going on here, I'd really appreciate it!

**EDIT** - here is the result when I redirect stderr to a file

FFmpeg version SVN-rUNKNOWN, Copyright (c) 2000-2007 Fabrice Bellard, et al.  configuration: --prefix=/usr
--libdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg --enable-libvorbis --enable-libogg --enable-libtheora --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaac --enable-libgsm --enable-xvid --enable-x264 --enable-liba52 --enable-liba52bin --enable-pp --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --disable-strip   libavutil version: 49.4.0   libavcodec version: 51.40.4   libavformat version: 51.12.1   built on Jun  4 2007 11:02:12, gcc: 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/path/to/7b4e37e703ce0a104f027cb9125b1a19.mp4': Duration: 00:00:32.4, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 122 kb/s   Stream #0.0(jpn): Video: h263, yuv420p, 176x144, 29.97 fps(r)   Stream #0.1(jpn): Audio: samr / 0x726D6173, 8000 Hz, mono

Output #0, flv, to '/path/to/test.flv':   Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 176x144, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps(c)   Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 8000 Hz, mono, 64 kb/s 
Stream mapping: Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 Stream #0.1 -> #0.1

Unsupported codec (id=73728) for input stream #0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What sort of access do you have to the server - you must have some ability to run commands on it.

That being the case, what is the error output from `ffmpeg`?

Possibly an appropriate verbose argument would tell you more about the problem?

EDIT:

Let's see if we can get stderr output.
Run:

```
ffmpeg -version
```

And see if you can get some output for it. Once you've managed to extract some stderr output then we can investigate the original issue.

EDIT:

So it looks like you're loosing `stderr` - now you need to work out how to retrieve it.

Maybe:

```
ffmpeg -version 2>&1
```

will work?

EDIT:

How we're getting somewhere - the input audio codec isn't supported:

```
Unsupported codec (id=73728) for input stream #0.1
```

I don't know what `Stream #0.1(jpn): Audio: samr / 0x726D6173, 8000 Hz, mono` is.

But there's you're problem.

I suggest that you might want to investigate on a local Linux box - it might be easier to see problems.

EDIT:

From http://www.nabble.com/Convert-3gp-samr-file-td20514476.html it looks like ffmpeg can be compiled with support `--enable-libamr-nb
--enable-libamr-wb`.

Is recompiling `ffmpeg` an option?

Comment: Probably not a file access problem if he's able to convert the file without audio. That being said, +1 for the verbose output to help diagnosis.

Comment: I'm using PHP's system function (http://php.net/system), which is returning 0. I've tried passthru, too, which doesn't output anything.

Comment: When I go for the ultra-simple ffmpeg -i $infile test.flv, it returns 1, if that helps.

Comment: Running -version doesn't output anything, but running -formats works, as does -L and -h!

Comment: Those all output some stuff to stdout - I tried -h first, before I worked out the -version only outputs to stderr.

Comment: Aha, redirecting stderr to a file does the trick - thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: Thank you - it seems that the issue is 3gp/MP4 format - which requires the libamr codecs! Thank you very much for your help - getting the stderr output was crucial in debugging this - I've learned something today!

Comment: +1 for the debugging process, including `ffmpeg -version 2>&1` which finally makes the `system('ffmpeg')` output everything I can see in the regular command prompt terminal. That `2>&1` alone is enough to diagnose the problems!

Comment: Alternative for `ffmpeg -version` for show version only: `ffmpeg -version | grep -oPi '(?<=ffmpeg ).*(?=http)'` Output example: `version 5.1.1-static` or `ffmpeg -version | grep -oPi '(?<=version ).*(?=http)'` Output example: `5.1.1-static`

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this issue. Here my code:

```
<?php
   define('FFMPEG_LIBRARY', '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg');
   $exec_string = FFMPEG_LIBRARY.' -i robot.avi -an output.flv';
   exec($exec_string); //where exec is the command used to execute shell command in php
?>
```